Trying to replace older outdoor light fixtures adding juction box and siding mount plate
I'm attempting to replace 3 outdoor lights that are mounted on older aluminum siding of a 1950s home. Because the siding is older, I am trying to do everything I can to not remove it for mounting block installation. The current wiring is just coming through a hole in the siding. Now that you have the situation, I'm hoping I can get some advice.

I found the mounting blocks I want to use that are designed to go over the siding without taking it down. They are made my Ply Gem and I can drill or cut into them no problem. I guess they are considered "flush mount"

Now I would like to add a junction box and I'm trying to decide if a pancake box on top of the siding is a good option or if I should cut a larger hole in to the siding and attach to sheathing with intent to flush mount a JB with the siding.


The concern I have with the second option is that because I have clapboard siding, mounting to the sheathing would leave the top part of the JB slightly further from the siding than that bottom (because the siding is angled and the box isn't). Sorry if this is confusing.
What would you folks do in this situation? I can add pics and product links if there's any questions that would help.

All three fixtures have the same holes. The existing JB you see in the hole is too deep to be useful even with extender.
This is mounting block I have chosen to go with.


How are the existing lights anchored? What is the material you describe as sheathing?

DelpicOracle, the lights are anchored to the siding by two nuts/bolts only through the siding and what I believe to the a material called celotex ( had to google it cause it's old) and the circular mounting ring thag comes with the fixture. it's really not up there  very securely.  As far as "sheathing goes, I haven't cut the opening any further yet but I can see some form of wood backer beyong the siding that was probably the original exterior of the home

@Freeeirr1916 I believe Traveler's point is that you should save your thousands of words and just give us some pics.

@Huesmann @ Traveler Understood and point taken. For the life of me I can't figure out how to add a picture to this post. Are you able to add pics when accessing through the phone?

Please take the [tour]. You've posted your images in answers, which is inappropriate.

I don't understand what the problem is. Can you post a pic of the new fixtures?  Why can't you just use the existing mounting ring and boxes?

Do you actually have siding?  Wood or vinyl?  We can't see enough from your pic of the old mount.  Personally, for vinyl, I prefer a flanged siding block, like the Arlington 8141F, because you can mount it anywhere on the wall.  The notched blocks like the one you have are only really good for new mounts—what do you do if your old sconce is at a different vertical location on the siding?

Had an electrician out to the house yesterday,  he gave me the answers I was looking for. I appreciate everyone who was attempting to help me. I need  more practice at this platform. Forgive me if I was posting incorrectly.
